# Cannot install Kubuntu 22.04 LTS release on Dell XPS 15 9520

Tags: 22.04, dell, xps, usb-installation

I am trying to install Kubuntu 22.04 LTS release on my Dell. Its failing.

Build: Kubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (not Daily Build)

ISO Verification was successful (gpg fingerprint check + sha256 checksum check)

USB disk was created using Startup disk Creator tool (Kubuntu 22.10)

Problem Descrition:

As soon as boot from USB and select the option "Try/Install Kubuntu..." my whole system feels very slow and it takes ages until I see some desktop.

Reaching that, as soon as I go through install process and I select my wifi, black screen appears. A weird one, where cursor is visible and movable.But no input possible anymore.

So no option except hard reset.

My syslog is flooded with varyous excpetions, no clue which of them is responsbile for this behaviour...

Secure boot is disabled and the weiredst thing of all: Kubuntu 22.10 runs just fine without any of these issues.

just an example of stack trace:

```
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.367991] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: timeout
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368002] WARNING: CPU: 6 PID: 251 at drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nvkm/subdev/bar/g84.c:35 g84_bar_flush+0xd6/0xe0 [nouveau]
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368031] Modules linked in: iwlmvm intel_tcc_cooling x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel mac80211 libarc4 kvm iwlwifi cfg80211 snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep uvcvideo snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi soundwire_bus snd_soc_core videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_common snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_ctl_led snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic videodev snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth mc snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm mei_hdcp mei_me mei ecdh_generic ecc snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq hid_sensor_als hid_sensor_trigger industrialio_triggered_buffer kfifo_buf hid_sensor_iio_common industrialio
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368052]  snd_seq_device snd_timer processor_thermal_device_pci processor_thermal_device processor_thermal_rfim intel_rapl_msr processor_thermal_mbox processor_thermal_rapl intel_rapl_common snd joydev input_leds cros_ec_ishtp cros_ec mac_hid soundcore hid_multitouch igen6_edac serio_raw dell_laptop rapl dell_wmi intel_cstate ledtrig_audio ucsi_acpi typec_ucsi dell_smbios typec dcdbas dell_wmi_sysman dell_wmi_descriptor wmi_bmof firmware_attributes_class intel_hid int3400_thermal int3403_thermal dptf_power int340x_thermal_zone acpi_thermal_rel sparse_keymap acpi_pad acpi_tad sch_fq_codel ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler msr parport_pc ppdev lp mtd parport ramoops efi_pstore reed_solomon pstore_blk pstore_zone ip_tables x_tables autofs4 overlay isofs uas usb_storage nls_iso8859_1 dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log hid_sensor_custom hid_sensor_hub intel_ishtp_loader intel_ishtp_hid hid_generic nouveau i915 nvme mxm_wmi drm_ttm_helper nvme_core ahci rtsx_pci_sdmmc libahci i2c_algo_bit ttm
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368075]  drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul cec ghash_clmulni_intel rc_core aesni_intel crypto_simd drm cryptd psmouse i2c_hid_acpi intel_lpss_pci i2c_i801 intel_ish_ipc i2c_hid intel_lpss xhci_pci thunderbolt i2c_smbus rtsx_pci idma64 vmd intel_ishtp xhci_pci_renesas wmi hid video pinctrl_tigerlake
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368084] CPU: 6 PID: 251 Comm: kworker/6:2 Tainted: G        W         5.15.0-43-generic #46-Ubuntu
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368085] Hardware name: Dell Inc. XPS 15 9520/0YD3W1, BIOS 1.10.0 12/14/2022
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368086] Workqueue: pm pm_runtime_work
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368087] RIP: 0010:g84_bar_flush+0xd6/0xe0 [nouveau]
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368114] Code: 8b 40 10 48 8b 78 10 4c 8b 77 50 4d 85 f6 75 03 4c 8b 37 e8 dc 54 f2 db 4c 89 f2 48 c7 c7 44 6a e9 c0 48 89 c6 e8 d1 48 39 dc <0f> 0b eb a6 e8 a1 a4 43 dc 90 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 49 89 c9 41 b8 00
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368115] RSP: 0018:ffffb2124096b488 EFLAGS: 00010082
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368116] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff9ef751651c00 RCX: 0000000000000027
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368116] RDX: ffff9f068f3a0588 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: ffff9f068f3a0580
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368117] RBP: ffffb2124096b4d8 R08: 0000000000000003 R09: 000000000007b828
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368118] R10: ffffffffffffffff R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffff9ef74132cd18
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368118] R13: 0000000000000246 R14: ffff9ef742f89020 R15: 0000000000060001
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368119] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9f068f380000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368120] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368121] CR2: 00007f564eb3e2fc CR3: 0000000afba10003 CR4: 0000000000770ee0
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368121] PKRU: 55555554
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368122] Call Trace:
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368122]  <TASK>
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368123]  nvkm_bar_flush+0x1c/0x30 [nouveau]
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368149]  nv50_instobj_release+0x31/0xa0 [nouveau]
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368182]  gp100_vmm_pd0_mem+0x1c0/0x1e0 [nouveau]
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368218]  nvkm_vmm_iter.constprop.0+0x319/0x730 [nouveau]
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368250]  ? gp100_vmm_mthd+0x110/0x110 [nouveau]
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368281]  ? gp100_vmm_mthd+0x110/0x110 [nouveau]
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368309]  ? nvkm_vmm_ref_sptes+0x1d0/0x1d0 [nouveau]
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368339]  nvkm_vmm_ptes_get_map+0x31/0xa0 [nouveau]
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368366]  ? nvkm_vmm_ref_sptes+0x1d0/0x1d0 [nouveau]
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368393]  ? gp100_vmm_mthd+0x110/0x110 [nouveau]
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368421]  nvkm_vmm_map_locked+0x1b9/0x330 [nouveau]
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368449]  nvkm_vmm_map+0x49/0x70 [nouveau]
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368475]  nvkm_vram_map+0x58/0x80 [nouveau]
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368507]  nvkm_uvmm_mthd_map.isra.0+0x1a6/0x240 [nouveau]
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368536]  nvkm_uvmm_mthd+0x54/0x410 [nouveau]
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368564]  nvkm_object_mthd+0x17/0x30 [nouveau]
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368588]  nvkm_ioctl_mthd+0x65/0x70 [nouveau]
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368612]  nvkm_ioctl+0xf3/0x1c0 [nouveau]
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368637]  nvkm_client_ioctl+0xe/0x10 [nouveau]
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368679]  nvif_object_mthd+0x16b/0x210 [nouveau]
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368703]  ? nvkm_client_ioctl+0xe/0x10 [nouveau]
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368739]  ? nvif_object_mthd+0x183/0x210 [nouveau]
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368763]  nvif_vmm_map+0x112/0x130 [nouveau]
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368787]  ? init_srcu_struct_nodes+0x430/0x520
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368789]  nouveau_mem_map+0x79/0xd0 [nouveau]
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368824]  nouveau_bo_move_m2mf+0x1ae/0x200 [nouveau]
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368856]  nouveau_bo_move+0xfe/0x320 [nouveau]
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368887]  ttm_bo_handle_move_mem+0xe1/0x210 [ttm]
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368890]  ttm_mem_evict_first+0x43f/0x680 [ttm]
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368893]  ? load_balance+0x730/0x850
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368894]  ttm_resource_manager_evict_all+0x9c/0x1e0 [ttm]
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368897]  ? pci_uevent+0x100/0x100
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368899]  nouveau_do_suspend+0x88/0x180 [nouveau]
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368929]  ? sched_clock_cpu+0x12/0xf0
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368930]  nouveau_pmops_runtime_suspend+0x3f/0xb0 [nouveau]
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368961]  pci_pm_runtime_suspend+0x5e/0x190
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368963]  __rpm_callback+0x4b/0x160
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368964]  ? pci_uevent+0x100/0x100
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368966]  rpm_callback+0x63/0x70
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368967]  ? pci_uevent+0x100/0x100
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368968]  rpm_suspend+0x164/0x750
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368970]  ? psi_task_switch+0xc6/0x220
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368971]  ? finish_task_switch.isra.0+0xa6/0x270
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368972]  pm_runtime_work+0x95/0xa0
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368973]  process_one_work+0x228/0x3d0
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368975]  worker_thread+0x53/0x410
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368977]  ? process_one_work+0x3d0/0x3d0
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368978]  kthread+0x127/0x150
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368980]  ? set_kthread_struct+0x50/0x50
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368981]  ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x30
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368983]  </TASK>
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.368983] ---[ end trace b9792074bf610d22 ]---
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.426299] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: timer: stalled at ffffffffffffffff
Jan 28 13:16:52 kubuntu kernel: [  116.426300] ------------[ cut here ]------------
```

any ideas what do do would be appreciated.

Comment: You weren't specific as to which Kubuntu 22.04 LTS you installed (22.04, 22.04.1 or *daily*), nor if you performed the basic checks (validation of ISO download, validation of media completed successfully), but the 22.10 you say worked uses the 5.19 kernel stack, where as kernel stack on 22.04 media varies on ISO (default is 5.15...).  If mouse still moves; you can direct the kernel to cleanly shutdown (ie. SysRq functions) & don't need to force power-off (ie. use keyboard & bypass any stuck UI/GUI app)

Comment: ok, well iso source is from here https://kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/ (Kubuntu 22.04.1 LTS).

Comment: to verify my download i did all the steps here, all were successful: (https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview)

Comment: @guiverc I edited my question to conform your critics. as i still do not get the problem because: 1, Release if it would be a daily build, I would mention it how specific it can be? 2. ISO Verification: you can assume that its verfied, without questioning my steps there. and 3. about SysRq maybe you're right but how this is helpful for me? I ask for a possibility to identify and resolve the error to be able to start the installation and not a cleanly shutdown.

Comment: My suggestion of the *daily* was that since the 5.19 kernel stack from 22.10 worked, I'd try a 22.04 ISO that contains the 5.19 kernel which will be released as 22.04.2; that ISO is still in *testing* thus it's a *daily*. Because of issues with the 5.17 SHIM there have been delays with *jammy* & I don't see the kernel yet on the daily (https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/jammy/daily-live/current/jammy-desktop-amd64.manifest) but it'll be there very soon  (*it would have been there already except for SHIM issues*)

Comment: thx, i will try

Comment: Just tried out, same error. And the weird thing is: I see in logs kernel 5.15 active, not 5.19 as expected? did I do something wrong?

Comment: You didn't specify who you were asking in last comment; but the *manifest* I provided shows it was the 5.15 kernel on the *daily* **currently**... Much of my last ~36 hours has focused on *lunar* due to inability to use GUI on dailies ($UID issue) now resolved, but I mentioned SHIM issues with 5.19 & *jammy* which has delayed their being placed on ISOs (*no use it being there if it can't boot*) but they're expected '*very soon*' (*late already; thus the two week delay on release; see* https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-22-04-2-delayed-until-february-23/33319)..  I check daily for QA reasons

Comment: @guiverc thx for the clearance and sorry for this inattentiveness. then I just wait until 22.04.2 is released...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kubuntu 23.04 is currently in BETA and the Final is scheduled to be released on April 20th, 2023 (about 2 weeks away). It comes with Kernel 6.2, and this may very well solve all your issues.
https://www.debugpoint.com/kubuntu-23-04/

Comment: actually, i finally did a workaround: I installed 20.04 & then upgraded to 22.04, worked fine